# Testing express with Mocha: a promise-based test will not run by itself?

Tags: node.js, express, promise, mocha.js

I have two test files.  When only test1.js is present, no tests run, and mocha reports "0 passing" tests.  When test1.js and test2.js are present but both depend on a promise, then still no tests run and mocha still reports "0 passing".  But when one of the tests is modified to not use a promise, mocha runs both tests and they succeed.  What the heck?  Here are my files:

index.js:

```
require('./server').then( function(server) {
  server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("Started server");
  });
);
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

module.exports = new Promise((function(resolve, reject) {
  return resolve(server);
}));
```

test1.spec.js:

```
require('./server').then(function(server) {
  describe('Test Suite #1', function () {
    it('should run test #1', function testSomething(done) {
      return done();
    });
  });
});
```

test2.spec.js (server.js used as promise, tests do *not* run):

```
require('./server').then(function(server) {
  describe('Test Suite #2', function () {
    it('should run test #2', function testSomethingElse(done) {
      return done();
    });
  });
});
```

test2.spec.js (server.js *not* used as promise, both tests run):

```
var server = require('./server');
describe('Test Suite #2', function () {
  it('should run test #2', function testSomethingElse(done) {
    return done();
  });
});
```

To run them, I just have nodejs, express, and mocha installed and run:

```
% mocha "*.spec.*"
```

I understand I'm not using the server variable in these examples, but of course the real tests need to return a promise because sometimes the server.js is accessing remote systems for config data.  I could work around this, but any help in understanding what's happening here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to describe and define all your tests synchronous. Otherwise they aren't recognized by mocha. If you have some async setup to make, use the before or beforeEach functions:

```
describe('Test Suite #1', function () {
  var server;
  before(function(done){
    require('./server').then(aServer => {
      server = aServer;
      done();
    });
  });
  it('should run test #1', function testSomething(done) {
    return done();
  });
});
```